# Can I use a filtered lookup field value in a workflow rule?

Tags: workflow, lookup-filter

I have a specific contact field (Agentname) in the Opportunity object. I want to make an email alert to this agent.

My rule criteria are something like:

```
AND(CONTAINS(AgentName__c ,'Mike'), 
ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Authorised'))
```

Because Agentname is a filtered lookup, as I understand it, Agentname__c resolves to an Id.

Is there anyway I can do the test `CONTAINS(AgentName__c ,'Mike')` in my workflow rule, or is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Rule Criteria you can use related object fields such as **Name** in your case.

This should work:

```
AND(CONTAINS(AgentName__r.Name ,'Mike'), 
ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Authorised'))
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks, @oles-malkov. I did find that I had to use the related field AgentName__r.FirstName as AgentName__r.Name gave a syntax error. (AgentName__c) is a filtered lookup on Account object).